# How do I use a custom MembershipProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a custom MembershipProvider with ASP MVC to secure controllers in my app.

Just for some background, I am going to use a web service eventually to authenticate each user.

As I understand it, I add it to the root level web.config as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="DANet.security.MyMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

And here is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace DANet.security
{
    public class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username,
           string password, string email, string passwordQuestion,
           string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved,
           object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool EnablePasswordReset
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
        {
            log.Debug("MyMembershipProvider");
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to see if the class is being utilized by NET and being called. As you can see, I have log statements in every method and nothing is getting logged when I log in OR when I try to hit a controller method marked as [Authorize]. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `defaultProvider` attribute to your membership-provider:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
```

[Configuring an ASP.NET Application to Use Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)